Does AWS Step Functions automatically update IAM role permissions when specifying a resource in Serverless Framework?
I'm using the Serverless Framework with the AWS Step Functions plugin to build a state machine for an order checkout flow. In one of the states, I'm trying to publish a message to an Amazon SNS topic. Here's the relevant part of my serverless.yml file:
PrepareOrder:
            Type: Task
            Resource: arn:aws:states:::sqs:sendMessage.waitForTaskToken
            Parameters:
              QueueUrl: !Ref OrdersQueue
              MessageBody:
                Input.$: "$"
                Token.$: "$$.Task.Token" #From the context object
            ResultPath: "$.courierStatus"
            Catch:
              - ErrorEquals: [NoCourierAvailable]
                ResultPath: "$.courierError"
                Next: RefundCustomer
            Next: DispatchOrder
DispatchOrder:
  Type: Task
  Resource: arn:aws:states:::sns:publish
  Parameters:
    TopicArn: "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:************:NotifyCourier"
    Message.$: "$"
  Next: Dispatched

In this configuration, I'm specifying the Resource as arn:aws:states:::sns:publish, which is the ARN for the SNS publish action.
I did not explicitly create an IAM role for this state machine. However, when I checked the IAM role associated with the state machine, I found that it had the sns:Publish permission. I also noticed that when I changed the Resource value, the permissions in the IAM role were updated accordingly.

Does AWS Step Functions automatically create and update an IAM role with the necessary permissions when I specify a resource like this in the Serverless Framework? Or is there some other mechanism at work here?

One way to verify this is check the generated cloudformation template file.
serverless package --stage dev --package ./tmp
Try changing the Resource value and run the command again.
Look for the cloudformation-template-update-stack.json under the tmp folder.
